# Regular expression to subtract 1 from a file name

Tags: regex, unix

In regular expression, i need to subtract 1 from a file name.

Rename:

```
W00524P.0210032021
```

to

```
W00524P.0209032021
```

Need to subtract 1 from 3rd and 4th character after dot. I have a pflow editor for regex:

```
^........(..)(..)(..)(....)
```

I am not getting the expected result by using:

```
W00524P.%{1}%{2-1}%{3}%{4}
```

This expression results in `W00524P.02%{2-1}032021`. Can you please provide the regular expression for this?

Comment: What is a _pflow editor for regrex_?

Comment: Regex cannot perform arithmetic. You would need to capture the result using some form of scripting and perform the arithmetic there.

Answer (score 2):

You may have the wrong mental picture of what a regular expression is.

A ‘regular expression’, as a pattern, allows you to ask the question ‘does this string match this pattern?’  That question is, at heart, the *only* question you can ask.

More sophisticated regular expression libraries (such as the one you're clearly using here) allow you to put `(...)` or `\(...\)` brackets round parts of the expression and thus extract specific parts of the matched string.

But that's it: regular expressions can't *do* anything.  This is the key *aha!*

The system that uses this regexp library (and I see you've tagged this with `ionic-appflow` – I've no idea what that is) will of course do something with the results of this match, but that's a question to ask of the documentation of that system.  That is, this is a long way of saying you're possibly asking a tangential question.

(Specifically, it looks like the regexp library you're using uses `%{n}` to refer to the n-th match; writing `%{2-1}`, if it meant anything, would refer to the 2-1-th match, and...)

Comment: Exactly. Well said. I added an answer with language specific extension, perl with execute in replace.

Answer (score 1):

As @Norman Gray pointed out in his answer, you can't do math with regular expressions.

Nevertheless, there are language specific extensions. Perl for example has a `e` flag to execute code in the replacement part of a search & replace.

Here is a shell example with a Perl one-liner that does what you want:

```
$ ls W00*
W00524P.0210032021
$ source=`ls W00*`
$ destination=`echo ${source} | perl -p -e 's/(?=.{8}$)(..)/sprintf("%02d", $1-1)/e'`
$ echo mv ${source} ${destination}
mv W00524P.0210032021 W00524P.0209032021
$ mv ${source} ${destination}
$ ls W00*
W00524P.0209032021
$
```

Explanation:

- set the `source` variable using back-ticks to execute the `ls`
- set the `destination` variable using back-ticks with pipes:

  - `echo ${source}` - output source filename
  - `perl -p -e 's/(?=.{8}$)(..)/sprintf("%02d", $1-1)/e'`:

    - do a perl `s/.../.../e` search & replace with `e` flag
    - `(?=.{8}$)` - positive lookahead to match the 8th char seen from the end
    - `(..)` - capture group 1 with two chars (`10` in our example)
    - `sprintf("%02d", $1-1)` - format a number to 2 digits with leading zero, teh value is `$1-1`, e.g. the capture group value minus 1
- `echo mv ${source} ${destination}` - just a demo how the mv looks like
- `mv ${source} ${destination}` - actual file rename